# InnoSetup - description file

Tags: file, associations, inno-setup

I created the installation using InnoSetup and there is a problem. I have a record of associating files with the application:

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".xsl"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "MyApp1"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks: mypAssociationXSL 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "XML Schema Definition"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Tasks: mypAssociationXSL 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\ProgTest.exe,0"; Tasks: mypAssociationXSL 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\ProgTest.exe"" ""%1"""; Tasks: mypAssociationXSL 

Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".xslt"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "MyApp1"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks: mypAssociationXSLT 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "XML Schema Definition"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Tasks: mypAssociationXSLT 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\ProgTest.exe,0"; Tasks: mypAssociationXSLT 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\ProgTest.exe"" ""%1"""; Tasks: mypAssociationXSLT 

Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".dtd"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "MyApp1"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks: mypAssociationDTD 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "Document Type Definition"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Tasks: mypAssociationDTD 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\ProgTest.exe,0"; Tasks: mypAssociationDTD 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyApp1\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\ProgTest.exe"" ""%1"""; Tasks: mypAssociationDTD
```

With mating is all right, but the description of each file appears:     Document Type Definition, although other values are as defined

Comment: Wait, and what is wrong on that a DTD description appears ? Btw. where it appears and what do you expect (obviously not showing that description, but where) ?

Comment: With DTD everything is fine . Problem lies in the fact that all extensions are defined last declared description . XLS is a description of the DTD , XSLT is a description of the DTD and the DTD file has the same name.

Probably somewhere in the definition was wrong , but I can not find the place .